# How to Conversion matrix to 1 row Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a this Dataframe

|  | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| o | 1 | 1 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| o | nan | nan | 2 | 2 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| o | nan | nan | nan | nan | 3 | 3 | nan | nan |
| o | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 4 | 4 |

I want to conversion this DataFrame

|  | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| o | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 |

How to make code use pandas..? I try numpy diagonal but it is failed

Comment: This is not a symmetric matrix. You need `df.groupby(level=0).first()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
a = df.values.flatten()
pd.DataFrame(a[~np.isnan(a)].reshape(-1,df.shape[1]), columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
     a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h
0  1.0  1.0  2.0  2.0  3.0  3.0  4.0  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = df.replace('nan', np.nan).groupby(level=0).first()
```